# Displaying Toast messages in text view

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using SQLite database to store and retrive data to my android application. In the following code I have retrived my table data to my screen using a toast message. I wanted to display all the records to my screen in textview. I am helpless in where to do changes. Would be really helpfull if somebody can help me with this code. Tried number of options and failed.

This is my main activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

             try {
        String destPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName()
                + "/databases/questions";
        File f = new File(destPath);
        if (!f.exists()) {
            CopyDB(getBaseContext().getAssets().open("questions"),
                    new FileOutputStream(destPath));
        }
    } 

             catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error File", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show(); 
    } 
             catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error IO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }

 Cursor cursor = db.getAllQuestions();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
                DisplayRecord(cursor);

            }
            while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        db.close();
    }

        public void CopyDB(InputStream inputstream, OutputStream outputstream)        
                throws IOException {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = inputstream.read(buffer))>0){
                outputstream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            inputstream.close();
            outputstream.close();
        }

        public void DisplayRecord(Cursor cursor){
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "id:" + cursor.getString(0) + "\n" +
                    "Question:" + cursor.getString(1) + "\n" +
                    "Answer:" + cursor.getString(2),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may want to use a dialog rather then a toast

Answer (score 0):

Create the `TextView` name it like textid in your `activity_main.xml` and then in DisplayRecord change `Toast` to `TextView`

IN `activity_main.xml`

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

IN `MainActivity`

```
public void DisplayRecord(Cursor cursor){

    TextView text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textid);
    text.setText(
        "id:" + cursor.getString(0) + "\n" +
        "Question:" + cursor.getString(1) + "\n" +
        "Answer:" + cursor.getString(2)
        );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But it is displaying only 1 record. How can I display all records?? I have around 10 records in my table.

Comment: use loop the records append the records value using  text.append(record fields)

Comment: I didnt get you. Please provide me an example\

Comment: U look to display all the records in a single textview

Comment: In one xml page i want to display all my 10 records. But is it possible?

Comment: Can I know how? How to loop the above output? AM I suposed to use a dialog insted of toast? Pls help.

Comment: @faz: _AM I suposed to use a dialog insted of toast?_ That is rather subjective. It also depends on what kind of data is being displayed. If the data records are independent of each other, you can loop through them and display them in a `ListView` or a `GridView` too.

Comment: THanks a lot. Since I am new to android I googled lots of samples but all ends up with errors Please could you provide a working example?